# Avoiding loops or list comprehension with numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Is it possible to replace

```
np.concatenate([np.where(x == i)[0] for i in range(y)])
```

with something that doesn't involve looping?

I want to take an array x, e.g. [0, 1, 2, 0 , 2, 2], and a number y, e.g. 2 in this case, and output an array [0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5].
E.g. for each integer in the array, write their index locations such that they're "in order".

Perhaps some kind of numpy function that can provide a performance boost over this list comprehension?

Comment: if `y=2` `np.concatenate([np.where(x == i)[0] for i in range(y)])` won't return [0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5] because `range(y)` gives an iterable of list `[0, 1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses `argsort`:

```
# settings
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0 , 2, 2])
y = 2

# sort the index
u = np.argsort(x)

# filter those that are larger than y
mask = x[u]<=y
u[mask]
```

Output:

```
array([0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5])
```

Comment: The problem with argsort is that it doesn't necessarily seem to return the indices in the order they appear in the array if the values are the same. E.g. np.argsort([0,1,0,0]) isn't guaranteed to return [0,2,3,1] - it could return [0,3,2,1]

Comment: Actually using the "stable" algorithm for sorting (kind="stable" in np.argsort) seems to preserve order in the desired way. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Using [argsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) would work.

```
numpy.argsort([0, 1, 2, 0 , 2, 2])
=> array([0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5])
```